# How can I trap a program that returns 139 (segmentation fault) in bash?

Tags: bash, signals, segmentation-fault, trap

I have a bash script that tests some programs and one of the program returns `Segmentation fault` so I tried to add a trap in the head of my script:

```
trap "echo 'segfault occured!'" SIGSEGV
```

That however didn't do anything. I used

```
echo $?
```

just after the program that produces the segfault and I get **139** as output.
How can I add a trap for that specific error code?

Answer (score 8):

`trap "$instructions" SIGSEGV` traps segmentation faults in the shell itself.

If you run your script under `set -e`, you can put a trap on `EXIT` (or `0`). It will be executed when your script terminates (whether due to a command returning a nonzero status, or by explicitly calling `exit` or by falling off the end of the script). To test for a segmentation fault, check `$?` on entry to the trap. (Note that `$?` could be 139 because the program returned normally with the status 139; this is avoidable if you do your processing in the shell.)

```
set -e
trap 'case $? in
        139) echo "segfault occurred";;
      esac' EXIT
```

In bash or ksh or zsh, you don't need to use `set -e` to execute a trap after each command that returns a nonzero status, you can put a trap on `ERR` instead. As before, you need to check `$?` on entry to the trap, and 139 can (but rarely does) mean that the program returned this status.

Answer (score 6):

From `man bash`:

```
   trap [-lp] [[arg] sigspec ...]
          The command arg is to  be  read  and  executed  when  the  shell
          receives  signal(s)  sigspec.
```

When your program segfaults, your bash just gets a `SIGCHLD` because some child exited (in whatever way).

You can, however, use the exitcode, stored in `$?`, in some conditional, and trap `SIGCHLD`:

```
trap 'if [[ $? -eq 139 ]]; then echo "segfault !"; fi' CHLD
```

Note that `set -bm` might be needed if this (what it probably does) is used in a non-interactive bash (such as a script).

**Edit:** See also [this (Gilles') answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/15744/confirmed-exit-using-trap/15759#15759) on a similar issue using `bash` and `trap`.

Comment: Something weird happens. I use trap `trap "echo 'something happened!'" {1..64}` and still I don't get anything. I even tryied with `set -bm` and `set -o monitor` but nada.

Comment: Have you tried this interactively? `trap "echo 'something happened'" {1..31}` works for me (leaving out the `!` and those signal specs that lead to `bash: trap: XX: invalid signal specification`).